# Using React's 'ref' attribute with Material-UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to access input data using React's "ref" attribute on a TextField in Material-UI. There doesn't seem to be an easy way of doing this via the 'inputRef' or 'inputProps'.

The below sample shows the use of  inputProps on line 26. Assigning the name of the TextField to the 'ref' property does not appear to produce a valid object.

With the “inputRef”, which according the [Material-ui](https://material-ui-next.com/api/text-field/) docs forces the use of a function, attempting to pass the field data in as an attribute also doesn't work. Ex: (txt => this.name = txt)

Has anyone found a solution?

```js
class MediaForm extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {}
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  handleSubmit (e) {
    const { title, colour } = this.refs
    e.preventDefault()
    window.alert(`New colour: ${title.value} ${colour.value}`)
  }

  render () {
    const { classes } = this.props
    return (
      <form className={classes.root}
        onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div className={classes.field}>
          <TextField
            name='title'
            type='text'
            label='Title'
            placeholder='Movie title...'
            autoFocus
            inputProps={{ref: this.name}}
            required />
        </div>
        <div className={classes.field}>
          <Tooltip title='Add a colour the reflects the mood of the film'>
            <TextField
              name='colour'
              type='color'
              label='Mood'
              inputProps={{ref: this.name}}
              required />
          </Tooltip>
        </div>
        <Button
          variant='raised'
          color='primary'
          className={classes.button}>
          ADD
        </Button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

MediaForm.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default withRoot(withStyles(styles)(MediaForm))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need refs for that. The submit event contains the form as the target. You can access the inputs in a form via `form.elements`:

```js
handleSubmit (event) {
    const { title, colour } = event.currentTarget.elements;
    event.preventDefault();
    window.alert(`New colour: ${title.value} ${colour.value}`);
}
```

To the problem with your refs: What does `this.name` refer to? You did not declare it anywhere so it is `undefined`. Passing `undefined` to the `ref` prop has no effect. Also how should it be possible to have two input refs being bound to the same instance property `name`. Are you aware that the `this` in your render function refers to the instance of your `MediaForm` component and therefore `this.name` is a property `name` on your component instance (which is undefined)?

If you want to obtain the individual refs for each input you should use the [callback pattern](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs). Note that [String refs are deprecated](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs) and should not be used:

```js
render() {
    return(
        <TextField
            name='title'
            type='text'
            label='Title'
            placeholder='Movie title...'
            autoFocus
            inputProps={{ref: input => this.titleInput = input}}
            required 
        />
    );
}
```

**EDIT:**

What you probably want is known as [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components). In this pattern your parent component keeps track of the values of it's children (often inputs):

```
class MediaForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            title: '',
            colour: '',
        };
    }

    handleChange = event => {
        const {name, value} = event.currentTarget;
        this.setState({[name]: value});
    };

    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const {title, colour} = this.state;
        window.alert(`New colour: ${title} ${colour}`);
    };

    render() {
        const {classes} = this.props;
        const {title, colour} = this.state;

        return (
            <form className={classes.root} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <div className={classes.field}>
                    <TextField
                        name="title"
                        type="text"
                        value={title}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        label="Title"
                        placeholder="Movie title..."
                        required
                    />
                </div>
                <div className={classes.field}>
                    <Tooltip title="Add a colour the reflects the mood of the film">
                        <TextField
                            name="colour"
                            type="color"
                            value={colour}
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                            label="Mood"
                            required
                        />
                    </Tooltip>
                </div>
                <Button
                    type="submit"
                    variant="raised"
                    color="primary"
                    className={classes.button}
                >
                    ADD
                </Button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

[image: Edit kxm42q76vv]

Now your parent has full control and access over the value of each input via `this.state.title` and `this.state.colour`. Also no need for any ref here.

Comment: You're right. My mistake. The <kbd>TextField</kbd>'s `inputProps` required a value, and definitely not ( `this.name`). I also appreciate that passing `ref` from input fields is not the recommended way of going about. However, the questions still remains: Is it possible to receive a value as input on a `Material-UI` <kbd>TextField</kbd>, assign it to `ref`, and then have it passed on to the submit handler to be accessed via `this.refs.title` and `this.ref.colour`?

Comment: @JohnLamy Just to understand that correctly: You basically want to have the values of the inputs accessible as variables in the parent component so that you can use them in the submit handler?

Comment: @JohnLamy You are welcome. If you feel like this solves your issue please upvote/mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me that I don't need to use refs or bind any events for this to work. Literally every React article about forms and events relies on refs and binding.

Comment: @JohnLamy how to use state in a form with multiple inputs, its terribly slow!

Answer (score 0):

```
class MediaForm extends Component {
  refs = {}  // <____ notice this
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {}
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  handleSubmit (e) {
    const { title, colour } = this.refs
    e.preventDefault()
    window.alert(`New colour: ${title.value} ${colour.value}`)
  }

  render () {
    const { classes } = this.props
    return (
      <form className={classes.root}
        onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div className={classes.field}>
          <TextField
            inputProps={{ref => this.refs.title = ref}}
            name='title'
            type='text'
            label='Title'
            placeholder='Movie title...'
            autoFocus
            required />
        </div>
        <div className={classes.field}>
          <Tooltip title='Add a colour the reflects the mood of the film'>
            <TextField
              name='colour'
              inputProps={{ref => this.refs.colour = ref}}
              type='color'
              label='Mood'
              required />
          </Tooltip>
        </div>
        <Button
          variant='raised'
          color='primary'
          className={classes.button}>
          ADD
        </Button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

MediaForm.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default withRoot(withStyles(styles)(MediaForm))
```

Comment: Looking at the your edited line 22:  ref= ={ref => this.refs.title = ref},
If you meant ref={ref => this.refs.title = ref}, don't think 'refs' can be passed into TextField as its a stateless component. Not to worry. I was only curious anyway. Thanks for  the prompt response.